# android broadcast receiver for no internet access

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I want to create a broadcast receiver for receiving intent when "No Internet Access" is happen. I already create a broadcast receiver for connectivity change but this is not what i need, because this receiver is called when not internet WIfi or mobile data. So how can i create receiver for no internet access?

```
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        }

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Well its sad to say that android OS does not have any broadcast for internet accessibility although it gives you broadcast for wifi|Data connectivity but that does not guarantee that internet is limited or not. There is a turnaround like

What you can do is to run a continuous task to hit some servers like google with IP 8.8.8.8 and if you get response that means internet is accessible.

If you need more information on running timer tasks you can read these

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Or

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score -1):

**1.create a class exteding by broadcast**

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        if(checkInternet(context))
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Network Available Do operations",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }
    }
    boolean checkInternet(Context context) {
        ServiceManager serviceManager = new ServiceManager(context);
        if (serviceManager.isNetworkAvailable()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**2. create a service to check internet ServiceManager.java**

```
public class ServiceManager extends ContextWrapper {

    public ServiceManager(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }
    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
        }
            return false;
        }
}
```

**3. In manifest file permissions :**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: how do i register the broadcats receiver ? with which intent ??

Comment: you can register using intent filter

Comment: using menifest file   <receiver android:name="NetworkChangeReceiver " >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="internet" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>